# Bootstrap navbar-toggle alway open

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to button (navbar-toggle ) was visible at any time I tested: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/m49Bb/ and it works 50/50. Button is all time. If I click button menu pops up at a moments and disappears.

Maybe more understandable:

1. Click on the button.
2. See menu for 2s.
3. Again, you don't see the menu.

I used Bootstrap v3.3.4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top always-open" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{projectTitle()}}</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    {{ menu() | raw}}
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar.always-open {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar.always-open .navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
.navbar.always-open .navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}
.navbar.always-open .navbar-collapse {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar.always-open .navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
}
.navbar.always-open .navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar.always-open .navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar.always-open .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What? I don't understand.... Is there even a question here?

Comment: Please explains better, seems to work fine.

Comment: Sorry. My english :( Better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in bootstrap.css
choose:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse{
  height:auto!important;
  padding-bottom:0;
  overflow:visible!important
}
```

(delete display: block !important)
and in my css:

```
.navbar.always-open .navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none;
}
.navbar.always-open .navbar-collapse.in {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: Just removing data-toogle value:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/Home/Index">Home<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="open">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Reportar <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#" style="font-size:12px;">b</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" style="font-size:12px;">c</a></li>
                            <li><a style="font-size:12px;">a</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```